# Xaml - Bind listviewitem source object

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, binding, windows-store-apps

I use an observableCollecion in my VM. This Collection is bind into my view in a ListView. In my items I try to get the element who create this item. Add it in my commandParameter and do the thing.

**Here's my VM :**

```
public RelayCommand<SelectionCommandParameter> CmdRemoveFromQuiz { get; set; } 
public ObservableCollection<Question> SelectedQuiz
{
   get { return _selectedQuiz; }
   set
   {
      _selectedQuiz = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedQuiz");
   }
}
private void RemoveFromQuiz(SelectionCommandParameter selection)
{
    if (selection.Parameter is Question)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Question> tempQuiz = SelectedQuiz; 
        Question _question = (Question)selection.Parameter;
        tempQuiz.Remove(_question);
        SelectedQuiz = tempQuiz;

    }
}
```

The problem start with the `RemoveBtn` I start the command, and `selection` stay `null` I want to get the `ObservableCollection<Question>` object use in my ListViewitem

**Now My View :**

```
        <userControls:CharmFlyout
        x:Name="cfoQuizList"
        x:Uid="QuizListCreatingPageFlyout"
        Heading="Question Multiple"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Style="{StaticResource stlAddRecipientFlyout}">
            <tut:TutorialAwareListView x:Name="gvQuizItem"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedQuiz}"
                          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                          CanReorderItems="True"
                          SelectionMode="None"
                          ManipulationMode="TranslateRailsX">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="DTQuizItem">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{StaticResource RectangleTileWidth}" Height="{StaticResource RectangleTileHeight}" 
                              Margin="0 0 0 0" Background="{StaticResource OrangeBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <Button x:Name="RemoveBtn" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Height="40" 
                                        BorderThickness="0" Command="{Binding DataContext.CmdRemoveFromQuiz, ElementName=gvQuizItem}" CommandParameter="{Binding Question}"/>
                                <maxCtrls:MaxAutoScrollingContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        ScrollingDuration="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource TextToTimeToReadShortFormatConverter}}"
                                        ScrollingBeginTime="0:0:2">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="SemiBold" 
                                               Foreground="{StaticResource WhiteBackground}"
                                               Margin="20,5,10,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                </maxCtrls:MaxAutoScrollingContentPresenter>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </tut:TutorialAwareListView>
        </userControls:CharmFlyout>
```

The TutorialAwareListView Work exactly like a ListView. I use it juste to point the element while the tutorial is running.

It's a *Windows Store App* !! I can't do all the thing we would like to.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your SelectionMode="None" to Single or Multiply. 
And make new ObservableCollection for selected items. You bind just ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedQuiz}". Bind SelectedItems="{...}"

Comment: Yeah, I just don't think that when you click on the removeBtn the item become Selected. I'll try and I tell you. thx a lot.

Comment: Nop. Don't work, with this the user have to select the item first. Too much to do.